# About problems of the process of Pyinstaller packing program: subprocess can't find

Tags: python

The IDE is Pycharm 2022.2.2 with Python 3.9, When I want to click my .exe file after using Pyinstaller packing my program, I got the below exception saying "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified".

I'm new to python (and Pycharm), so not sure what file was missing as the exception message didn't include a filename. Any hint will be highly appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txuNi.png)